# How to update res when an inner join is null?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm grabbing a specific question from my database and I'm doing a left outer join in order to also include the question's options (possible answers) in the results.

```
Question.findAll({
    where: { id: questionData.question_id, status: 1 },
    include: [{
        model: QuestionOption,
        as: 'QuestionOptions',
        attributes: ['id', 'text'],
        required: false,
    }]
})
```

Now if there are results in QuestionOptiosn they're included in the result. All is right in the world.

```
"QuestionOptions": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "42"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "43"
    }
],
```

But when no options are found and my QuestionOptions is [], I want to manually insert options there.

I've tried using setDataValue but I can't seem to manually override that empty QuestionsOptions array. When I attempt setDataValue, I get this error message:

```
message: 'instance.get is not a function',
```

Is there not a way to force update that empty array?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't know if this is the right approach but I created a virtual datatype on my model like so:

```
var Model = sequelize.define('Question', {
    ...
    options: {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
        set: function(val) {
            this.setDataValue('options', val);
        }
    }
}
```

In my service and after I have my results, I check to see if there are any results with QuestionsOptions. If I do, then I update my options with those values.

```
question[0].setDataValue('options', question[0].QuestionOptions);
```

If QuestionOptions is empty, then I update my options with default values like so:

```
question[0].setDataValue('options', [{ text: "True" }, { text: "False" }]);
```

And in my view, I know that `options` will always have the option values I should use in my application.

But this is only good when I know I only want 1 result. Not sure how to handle this when there are multiple questions returned.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the most straightforward way would be to do

```
.then(result => {
  if(result.length === 0){
   result[0] = //whatever you want it to be here
  }
}
```

after your `Question.findAll`